# What software can affect a Bertor?

Tags: space-rangers-hd

These big ships are super annoying since they constantly spawn small kamikaze ships that does tons of damage.  Also, the kamikaze ships are so fast that its hard to shoot at them before they've already collided with your ship.  However, none of the high end software I've tried (like System Shutdown) seem to work against the Bertor.  Are there any lower level software that might work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying them all, I'm forced to conclude that Bertors are completely immune to any form of hacking what so ever.